# It is showing command not found for sudo add-apt-repository on elementary OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elementaryos

Here's a photograph of terminal -
[Image of command line terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3YNs.png)

I was trying to install the following repository -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
```

but it is showing command not found for Elementary OS.

I have been unable to add repositories due to this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the command a little backwards.

Try:

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
```

Be sure to run this after adding the repo:

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

So that way we know for sure that we are getting the latest package.